# How use varaible as column name in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would make this code shorter.

```rb
def foo type, user
  if type == "foo"
    user.foo
  elsif type == "bar"
    user.bar
  end
end
```

`user` is ActiveRecord object

`type` is string "foo" or "bar"

If I have more `types` then I need to make more `elsif`. It's possible to make it shorter (without using the model method or any other additional code) using `type` variable as a column name? Something like:

```rb
user.{type} # ???
```

Comment: Type will always be equal to the method name? If so, you may use `user.public_send(type)`

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `public_send` to achieve this:

```rb
user.public_send(type)
```